# How can I force exiting a perl subroutine/closure via last/next to fail the program automatically?

Tags: perl, closures

Given the following fully functional perl script and module:

***tx_exec.pl***:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; # make sure $PWD is in your PERL5LIB
# no warnings!

use tx_exec qw(tx_exec);

tx_exec ("normal", sub { return "foobar"; });
tx_exec ("die", sub { die "barbaz\n"; });
tx_exec ("last", sub { last; });
tx_exec ("next", sub { next; });
```

***tx_exec.pm***:

```
package tx_exec;

use strict;
use warnings;

require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(tx_exec);

my $MAX_TRIES = 3;

sub tx_exec {
    my ($desc, $sub, $args) = @_;
    print "\ntx_exec($desc):\n";
    my $try = 0;
    while (1) {
        $try++;
        my $sub_ret;
        my $ok = eval {
            # start transaction
            $sub_ret = $sub->($args);
            # commit transaction
            1;
        };

        unless ($ok) {
            print "failed with error: $@";
            # rollback transaction
            if ($try >= $MAX_TRIES) {
                print "failed after $try tries\n";
                return (undef, undef);
            }
            print "try #$try failed, retrying...\n";
            next;
        }
        # some cleanup
        print "returning (1, ".($sub_ret//'<undef>').")\n";
        return (1, $sub_ret);
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
$ ./tx_exec.pl
tx_exec(normal):
returning (1, foobar)

tx_exec(die):
failed with error: barbaz
try #1 failed, retrying...
failed with error: barbaz
try #2 failed, retrying...
failed with error: barbaz
failed after 3 tries

tx_exec(last):

tx_exec(next):
# infinite loop
```

I understand what is happening, and I'm getting a warning about it if I turn on warnings in the script defining the closures. However, can I force the program to fail/die automatically/idiomatically, when next/last would exit a closure-subroutine like here, under the following strict circumstances:

- The `$sub` being passed is a closure and not a simple function (a simple function dies on bare `next/last` anyway, which is trivial to handle)
- The library code (`tx_exec`) and the client code (invoking it) are in separate compilation units and the client **does not use warnings**.

Using perl 5.16.2 (without possibility of upgrading).

Here is a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/Irfy/b41264f0067c921b3a25dd0bc6504dcd) documenting all the approaches so far:

- `use warnings FATAL => qw(exiting)` doesn't make a difference in library code
- `local $SIG` handler doesn't work if the call site doesn't have `FATAL => qw(exiting)` warning enabled
- *manual* detection works, but is somewhat cumbersome and all over the place (nonlocalized)
- ysth's approach with a bare block works best, as it catches the last/next, fully localizing manual detection and guaranteeing that nothing can go wrong (except next/last with labels, which is easier to avoid).

Comment: don't have a 5.16.2 to try, but you should be able to add (after your `use warnings;`) `use warnings FATAL => 'exiting';`

Comment: Unfortunately that only works if it is given at every site where `tx_exec` is called. Imagine it as a library routine which is included as a perl module from some middleware. There are hundreds of sites calling `tx_exec`, passing it a subroutine, and I'd like to catch them all at the `tx_exec` site. (As I said, with about 5-6 lines of code, it can be done manually, just exploring possibilities of a *saner* Perl)

Comment: Can implement it in the `WARN` hook in the sub, say `local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {  die @_ if $_[0] =~ /Exiting subroutine via (?:last|next)/; warn @_ };`

Comment: you should be able to put it inside your eval; have `eval { use warnings FATAL => 'exiting'; { ... } }` where ... is your existing code.  (The added bare block around it is important)

Comment: Interesting. It works, but this time the error is not printed, so it's kind of shooting me in the foot by masking the original error... Why is the bare block that important. Out of curiosity I tried and saw that it is indeed essential.

Comment: "_but this time the error is not printed_"  -- I get it printed, with a line number and all (see my answer) ?

Comment: I'll have to take my comment back, it is indeed printed with my own example (after splitting it into a `.pm` and a `.pl`). It is not getting printed in my production environment with the actual middleware exhibiting the problem -- I guess I have some other factors at play that would suppress that output there. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to reproduce my issue: if the calling site doesn't have the warning enabled, the warning isn't printed. Try it with a `.pl` with no warnings, calling `tx_exec` from an imported `.pm` module which does have the warnings.

Comment: A bare block is a loop, so next/last apply to it.  It wouldn't stop e.g. `next SOMELABEL` if that existed.

Comment: Re "*but I'm hoping for a more idiomatic approach*", Turning on warnings is the idiomatic approach. Trying to support code that doesn't do this is a bad idea. If they want to hang themselves, let them. Them using `next`/`last` incorrectly is not your problem.

Comment: The warnings in the caller fire merely on code `sub { last; }` that is _in the caller_. There's still plenty to work with in your module even if the caller turns off warnings (what you shouldn't fight against, btw).

Comment: @ikegami It's always more complicated than that :) The person who wrote the bad client code is on the same team that wrote the library code. It's a mistake. And it led to an infinite loop in production, producing huge log files under sensitive circumstances -- unacceptable stuff. In the end, it *is* my problem, if client code clobbers my library code.

Comment: Nonsense. That actually makes it simpler! You can actually have them fix the problems (the first being the lack of warnings). And you can make the warning fatal on the other side

Comment: @ysth It seems that I can flag that the sub returned properly within the bare block, and check it just after the bare block to determine if the return from the sub was caused by `next/last`. This comes closest to an *idiomatic* solution: it's succinct and very localized. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of @ysth's involvement in writing an answer, I'm writing the best solution I found so far, inspired by his first attempt from the comments to the question. (I will re-accept ysth's answer if he posts it later).

---

The `eval` calling the coderef needs to look like this:

```
my $ok = eval {
    # start transaction
    my $proper_return = 0;
    {
        $sub_ret = $sub->($args);
        $proper_return = 1;
    }
    die "Usage of `next` or `last` disallowed in coderef passed to tx_exec\n" unless $proper_return;
    # commit transaction
    1;
};
```

The bare block is acting as a loop which will immediately exit on either `next` or `last`, so whether we land after the bare block, or within it, from calling the coderef, we can deduce whether the coderef executed `next/last` and act appropriately.

More on bare block semantics and their interaction with `next/last` can be found [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/prog/ch04_05.htm).

*It is left as an exercise for the reader to handle the rarely seen `redo` in the code above.*

Answer (score 2):

**Short**   Using `next`/`last` in the sub (that caller passes as coderef) triggers an exception, if not within a "loop block." This affords an easy handling of such use, with a small change of `tx_exec()`.

---

The wrong use of `last`/`next` raised in the question is a little nuanced. First, from [last](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html)

> `last` cannot be used to exit a block that returns a value such as `eval {}`, `sub {}`, or `do {}`, and should not be used to exit a `grep` or `map` operation.

and for doing this in a sub or `eval` we get a warning

```
Exiting subroutine via last at ...
```

(and for "eval"), and similarly for `next`. These are classified as `W` in [perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) and can be controlled by using/not the `warnings` pragma.<sup>†</sup> This fact foils attempts to make such use fatal by `FATAL => 'exiting'` warning or by `$SIG{__WARN__}` hook.

However, if such use of `next` or `last` (in a sub or `eval`) *has no "loop block" in any enclosing scope (or call stack) then it also raises an exception*.<sup>‡</sup> The message is

```
Can't "last" outside a loop block...
```

and similarly for `next`.  It is found in [perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) (search for `outside a loop`), classified as `F`.

Then one solution for the posed problem is to run the coderef passed by caller *outside of loop blocks*, and we get the interpreter to check for and alert us to (raise exception) the offending use.  As the `while (1)` loop is there only to be able to try multiple times this can be implemented.

The coderef can be run and tested against this exception in a utility routine

```
sub run_coderef {
    my ($sub, @args) = @_; 

    my $sub_ret;
    my $ok = eval { $sub_ret = $sub->(@args); 1 };
    if (not $ok) { 
        if ($@ =~ /^Can't "(?:next|last)"/) {  #'
            die $@;                            # disallow such use
        }
        else { return }                        # other error, perhaps retry
    }   
    else { return $sub_ret }
}
```

which can be used like

```
sub tx_exec {
    my ($sub, @args) = @_; 

    my $sub_ret = run_coderef($sub, @args);

    my $run_again = (defined $sub_ret) ? 0 : 1;

    if ($run_again) { 
        my $MAX_TRIES = 3;
        my $try = 0;

        while (1) { 
            ++$try;
            $sub_ret = run_coderef($sub, @args);

            if ( not defined $sub_ret ) {  # "other error", run again
                if ($try >= $MAX_TRIES) { 
                    print "failed after $try tries\n";
                   return (undef, undef);
                }
                print "try #$try failed, retrying...\n";
                next;
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This approach makes perfect sense design wise: it allows an exception to be raised for the disallowed use, and it localizes the handling in its own sub.

The disallowed behavior is checked for really only on the first run, since after that `run_coderef` is called out of a loop, in which case (this) exception isn't thrown. This is fine since the repeated runs (for "allowed" failures) are executed with that same sub so it is enough to check the first use.

On the other hand, it also means that we can

- run `eval { $sub_ret = $sub->(@args) ... }` directly in the `while (1)`, since we *have* checked for bad use of `last`/`next` on the first run
- Can add further cases to check for in `run_coderef`, making it a more rounded checker/enforcer. The first example is the `Exiting` warnings, which we can make fatal and check for them as well. This will be useful if warnings in the caller are enabled

This approach *can* be foiled but the caller would have to go out of their way toward that end.

Tested with v5.16.3 and v5.26.2.

---

<sup>†</sup> Btw, you can't fight a caller's decision to turn off warnings. Let them be. It's their code.

<sup>‡</sup> This can be checked with

```
perl -wE'sub tt { last }; do { tt() }; say "done"'
```

where we get

```
Exiting subroutine via last at -e line 1.
Can't "last" outside a loop block at -e line
```

while if there is a "loopy" block

```
perl -wE'sub tt { last }; { do { tt() } }; say "done"'
```

we get to see the end of the program, no exception

```
Exiting subroutine via last at -e line 1.
done
```

The extra block `{ ... }` "*semantically identical to a loop that executes once*" ([next](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html)).

This can be checked for `eval` by printing its message in `$@`.

---

*The original post, based on the expectation that only warnings are emitted*

The [warnings pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) is lexical, so adding per ysth comment

```
use warnings FATAL => 'exiting';
```

in the sub itself (or in `eval` to scope it more tightly) should work under the restrictions

```
sub tx_exec { 
    use warnings FATAL => "exiting"; 

    my ($sub, $args) = @_; 
    $sub->($args);        
};
```

since the warning fires inside the `tx_exec` scope. In my test the call to this with a coderef not doing `last/next` first runs fine, and it dies only for a later call with them.

Or, can implement it using `$SIG{__WARN__}` ["signal" (hook)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%SIG)

```
sub tx_exec {   
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { 
        die @_ if $_[0] =~ /^Exiting subroutine via (?:last|next)/; 
        warn @_ 
    };

    my ($sub, $args) = @_;
    ...
}
```

Comment: The `local $SIG` solution seems as the most useful to me. It localizes the handling to one place and allows me to emit custom diagnostics/actions when this happens.

Comment: Ooops. None of the solutions work if the calling site has no warnings enabled, which returns us to the starting point... Try the code with a module and a script, and make sure the script calling `tx_exec` has no warnings enabled. This is also the reason why I originally said that I get nothing printed. Adding the bare block modifies the behavior, but if no warnings are enabled at call site, I get no warning output. Can the imported module force the warning at the call site?

Comment: Let's take a step back: I don't care about the "Can't next/last" from a proper function. That will raise an exception any time, which will properly terminate the eval. The problem is *only* when client using next/last skips the rest of the loop in library code. I only care about the next/last from a closure that doesn't `die` under normal circumstances, and doesn't `warn` without warnings enabled. So far it seems that I can't force the warning in client code (could I actually do that?) unless the client is using warnings by themselves. This makes my library less robust.

Comment: @Irfy OK, I don't understand.  You have `$sub->($args);` under `eval`, what runs client's code (which has `last` in a sub).  So it throws, it's handled by eval, and it's available right under `unless ($ok)`.  So if you test `$@` you'll see whether `last` happened, etc.  No?

Comment: @Irfy The client's bad code (with `last` in a sub) runs in your `rx_exec` and throws an exception; you have on your hands all you need. No?

Comment: @Irfy "_The problem is only when client using next/last skips the rest of the loop in library code._"  --- how do they do that?  If they have `next` or `last` there'll be an exception and you're in business.

Comment: @Irfy  "_from a closure_" -- I don't see any closures?  ...  "_that doesn't `die` under normal circumstances, and doesn't warn without warnings enabled._"  -- but, how? The code you show _does_ "die" (but is `eval`-ed), due to that next/last.

Comment: When passed a function, a bare `next/last` will die and I can catch it. But in my problem definition, `$sub` is a closure (there are four closures passed from the main part of the script in my example). Yes, it runs in `tx_exec`, but it doesn't throw an exception if the module/script that defines the closure has no fatal warnings. To illustrate, run the code from my git gist **verbatim** (so two files, using either of the two non-working approaches there, except the manual approach) and you will understand my point immediately.

Comment: I used *subroutine* and *closure* as synonyms in my question, sorry about that -- perl uses *subroutine* to mean *closure* in its warning message, that's why. When `next/last` is executed in a function, it dies and prints a different message altogether. **That case is trivial, and not the subject matter of my question** (sorry for not making it clear in the beginning).

Comment: @Irfy Oh, I got it. I'm not crazy and neither are you: question code, verbatim, does not throw, but with a _slight_ tweak (that I have) it does! It's not about a closure (which you don't use), but about there being-or-not a "loop block" _anywhere_ up the scope (so it seems); if there isn't it dies. This is interesting. I'll figure out a nice solution.

Comment: @Irfy Updated.  My previous tests never had an enclosing loop (like your `while (1)`) since I didn't think I needed it ... so I got the exception; one doesn't with a loopy block anywhere in any higher scope. Sorry about that.  Fixed: by calling the passed code outside of any loops you get the exception for (their use of) `last/next`, what allows you to handle it.  I've implemented it by running the coderef outside of `while` the first time.  I think that using interpreter's exception and handling that in a separate sub is a good solution. There sure are other ways to do this.  Let me know

Comment: Now the solution seems to work :) One important nitpick though: *it also means that we can run ... directly in the while (1), since we have checked for bad use of last/next on the first run*. Imagine a concurrent system with some sort of locking. If we fail to lock early the first time and return, we retry and could succeed the second time and later trigger our erroneous `next/last` -- perfectly valid, no "going out of our way" scenario, that could make things go awry, so I would stick to calling the `$sub` in a `sub` **always**. But nice approach, +1.

Comment: I spoke to soon again :( As stated in my last comment, if we run `run_coderef` always inside the loop, the `next/last` will still "see" that there is a loop around the calling sub and will still not fail with exception! In other words, your solution doesn't work, even if we keep the first run before the loop, if by (legitimate) chance, the second run triggers a `next/last`. This is horrible :( Thanks for your effort, but even this doesn't work (at least not up to the standard of robustness I'm going for). I think @ysth's local bare block with manual detection is the way to go.

Comment: @Irfy  "_the second run triggers a `next/last`_"  -- Well, this is what I meant by "_... go out of their way_", and I don't see how it is "_by (legitimate) chance,_". Sorry if I didn't explain it well : your sub receives their coderef. It runs it, and then _your sub decides_ that the run failed, and runs it (the same coderef) again.  That coderef would have to _know that it has been run once_ and to change what it's doing on the second run!  Nah, not "legitimate."   Can do it, sure, but that'd be malicious code.  (What still is a possibility, thus the "out of their way" note.)

Comment: @Irfy Note: I am just discussing code, not trying to persuade you one way or the other. You do (and in particular "accept") whatever suits you best of course

Comment: I'm talking here about a very simple, legitimate thing. We try to get a lock in a concurrent system in the beginning of our code and fail => retry. On our second attempt, we get it, and later trigger the (unintended/mistaken) `next/last`. Another legitimate example in a concurrent system would be that the state in a database has changed, causing a different code path in our coderef to be taken on retry, triggering the `next/last` in that path. We would have to pretend that real-world code has no "alternative control paths that can be taken due to changes in the system in different executions".

Comment: Having argued about this a bit, please keep in mind that I majorly appreciate your attempts, analysis and potential solutions to my problem, I'm sure to have learned from your answer, in any case :) It just so turns out that Perl is the culprit here, with its `setjmp/longjmp`-like-semantics in it cross-sub-jumping `next/last/redo` making all those attempts not sufficiently robust for my environment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I went out of my way to present, in pseudo-code, some realistic conditions applicable to production systems, to corroborate my "legitimately only on second try" argument: https://gist.github.com/Irfy/5543b32efdb88777b61aa249f94894cc This pseudo-code is vaguely similar to the actual production code that prompted me to dive deeper into the issue and post this question in the first place. The original reason for the `next` to be there, is because this code was migrated from an older system that didn't have such coderef-within-transaction concept and `next` was the tool of choice for flow control.

Comment: @Irfy Oh yes, those are good use cases; I wasn't thinking straight.  Don't even need concurrency, just dynamical decisions to `last`/`next`-or-not. I'll think a little more.

Comment: @Irfy   Btw, there is _nothing_ wrong with catching it manually with an extra block like you have it now -- let it play, allow it to do its `next`/`last` thing and detect that. I like that, in particular in the light of your explanation that the problem _is_ due to (the original) flow control. (I was puzzled as to why that coderef gives you bare `next`.) I'm just trying to find an interpreter-managed solution as well.

Comment: @Irfy  "_to present, in pseudo-code, some realistic conditions ... pseudo-code is vaguely similar to the actual production code_"  -- yes, this is good and makes the point.  Btw, curious code I must say (the production-alike code you show).

Answer (score 1):

This is the *manual* approach I was mentioning in the question. So far this was the only approach that helped me cleanly handle misbehaving client code, without any assumptions or expectations.

I'd prefer, and will gladly consider, a *more idiomatic* approach, like the `local $SIG` or `use warnings FATAL => 'exiting'`, **if they work without any expectation from client code** (specifically that it has warnings enabled in any form).

***tx_exec.pl***:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
# no warnings!

use tx_exec qw(tx_exec);

tx_exec ("normal", sub { return "foobar"; });
tx_exec ("die", sub { die "barbaz\n"; });
tx_exec ("last", sub { last; });
tx_exec ("next", sub { next; });
```

***tx_exec.pm***:

```
package tx_exec;

use strict;
use warnings;

require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(tx_exec);

my $MAX_TRIES = 3;

sub tx_exec {
    my ($desc, $sub, $args) = @_;
    print "\ntx_exec($desc):\n";
    my $try = 0;
    my $running = 0;
    while (1) {
        $try++;
        my $sub_ret;
        my $ok = eval {
            # start transaction
            die "Usage of `next` disallowed in closure passed to tx_exec\n" if $running;
            $running = 1;
            $sub_ret = $sub->($args);
            print "sub returned properly\n";
            # commit transaction
            1;
        };

        $running = 0;

        unless ($ok) {
            if ($@ =~ /^Usage of `next`/) {
                print $@;
                return (undef, undef); # don't retry
            }
            print "failed with error: $@";
            # rollback transaction
            if ($try >= $MAX_TRIES) {
                print "failed after $try tries\n";
                return (undef, undef);
            }
            print "try #$try failed, retrying...\n";
            next;
        }
        # some cleanup
        print "returning (1, ".($sub_ret//'<undef>').")\n";
        return (1, $sub_ret);
    }
    print "Usage of `last` disallowed in closure passed to tx_exec\n";
    return (undef, undef);
}
```

***output***:

```
tx_exec(normal):
sub returned properly
returning (1, foobar)

tx_exec(die):
failed with error: barbaz
try #1 failed, retrying...
failed with error: barbaz
try #2 failed, retrying...
failed with error: barbaz
failed after 3 tries

tx_exec(last):
Usage of `last` disallowed in closure passed to tx_exec

tx_exec(next):
Usage of `next` disallowed in closure passed to tx_exec
```